# Code Runner extension in VS Code doesn't output code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I have installed the extension Code Runner for VS Code and it doesn't output any code. All that happens is that it goes to the terminal and writes path to file> python -u and path to file again but within "". Nothing is written in output either. I have python installed and even the extension for vs code. I have saved the file as well. Using run and debug works but not Code Runner.

Comment: Could you show us a minimal example and the corresponding output?

Comment: You can find the `"code-runner.executorMap"` in the settings, the python entry should look something like this `"python": "python -u".`

Comment: This is what I get in the terminial: 
PS C:\Users\nickd\PycharmProjects\SecondSchoolProject> python -u "c:\Users\nickd\PycharmProjects\SecondSchoolProject\first.py"

Comment: I have found executor map and "python": "python -u"

Comment: Try setting `"code-runner.runInTerminal"` to `false`, so the output will appear in the output tab. Also make sure the script does have some output und is the same script you already debugged.

Comment: @Nicholas Chill Does the console have the expected output when you use"Run python File in Terminal"? How about when using code debugging?

Answer (score 0):

In "Output" tab, just to the left side of the "**clear output**" icon, you have a drop-down list (combo box/select). You get Tasks, Python...Code...

[image: ( Here's an image)]

**Select Code.**

This solution was tested on Windows, I don't know if it works on Mac.